# how to pass a variable to a subroutine to send email in perl

Tags: perl, email, subroutine

I want to be able to send an email if the contents of a variable are not empty

this is my code:

```
my $output = $ssh->capture({stdin_data => <<'EOS'}, 'pfexec /usr/bin/perl');

use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '/dir';

my $today = time();
my $onehour = $today - (60*60);
my $oneday = $today - (24*60*60);

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name("*.0")
                            ->mtime(">$oneday")
                            ->mtime("<$onehour")
                            ->in( "$dir" );

for my $file (@files) {
    print "$file\n";
}

EOS

sub send_email{

use MIME::Lite;

$to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
$cc = 'efgh@mail.com';
$from = 'webmaster@yourdomain.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';


$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Cc       => $cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Data     => $output
                 );

$msg->send;

}
if ($output) {
        send_email($output);
}
```

as you can see i connect remotely to a server. find a few files and if files are found send them by email. 
I do not know how to create the subroutine so it takes the `$output` as parameter and sends it by mail.

thanks

Comment: I see some grave scoping errors. Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Comment: The code looks "ok" to me, but you should add strict and warnings, like ikegami suggested, and use `my $from` etc. inside the sub. to learn how to pass variables to subroutines, check [perldoc perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: the code above is just a snippet of the whole script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're asking how subroutines receive parameters? It's through the `@_` array. I did a little rewrite of your sub below.

Note: `use Mime::Lite;` should move outside the sub...it's probably best to move it all the way to the top. All `use` modules is always runned first anyway, no matter where it's at in your code, so it might as well be listed close to the top. Also, it's often useful to view all dependencies at one place. On the slight chance you absolutely don't want to load the Mime::Lite module unless send_email is called, use `require Mime::Lite;` instead of `use` inside the sub, it will then be included the first time the sub is called.

Remember to use  `my` for local vars so you don't get trouble with others vars using the same name as your program grows (known as namespace pollution)

```
use MIME::Lite;
...
my $output = $ssh->capture( ... );
...
sub send_email {
  my($data) = @_;
  my $subject = 'Test Email';
  my($to,$cc,$from) = ('abcd@gmail.com',
                       'efgh@mail.com',
                       'webmaster@yourdomain.com');
  my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Cc       => $cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Data     => $data,
            );
  $msg->send;
}

send_email($output) if $output;
```

Comment: does the mail sent here take the system mail configuration eg: postfix. that is configured to send authenticated mail via an exchange server. or is it necessary to add authentication data to to the subroutine?

Comment: Don't know about postfix. This might be what you're looking for: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#Change_how_messages_are_sent